# Jorani [Open Source Leave Management] - Local Server Issue

Tags: server, localhost

I have hosted the [jorani Open Source LMS](http://jorani.org/), under local server and after logging in, redirects me to home page (http://localhost/lms/home), but I get a **404 - File or directory not found.** error. 
What can I do to fix this? I know I need a server configuration but I don't know what. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't activate the rewrite module.

Jorani contains a page at the root of the installation (e.g. http://localhost/lms/requirements.php) that checks your system and tell you what is missing.

You should read the [manual of installation](https://github.com/bbalet/jorani/tree/master/docs/install).

Comment: I am using IIS7, not Apache. Check the picture up.

Comment: @TufiSinjour whether your are using IIS, nginx or Apache you need to activate rewrite rules. Please read the doc: https://github.com/bbalet/jorani/tree/master/docs/install#iis7